These constrained alternating series always satisfy an inequality.
Let $x_0 \in \Bbb{N}$ and suppose that $x_1 \lt \frac{x_0}{2}$, while $0 = x_n \leq \dots \leq x_3 \leq x_2\leq x_1$.
Then is it possible that:
$$
\sum_{i = 0}^n (-1)^i x_i \gt 1
$$
no matter what choices are made for $x_1, \dots x_{n-1}$ in $[0, \dots, \frac{x_0}{2}) \cap \Bbb{N}$?
Note that keeping the variables $x_i \in \Bbb{N}$ instead of $\Bbb{R}$ has the advantage of having only a finite number of cases to check for each $x_0 \in \Bbb{N}$.
For example:
$$
x_0= 4, x_1 = 1, x_2=1, x_3=1, x_4 = 0 \\
4 - 1 + 1 -1 + 0 = 3 \gt 1 \\
4 - 1 + 1 - 0 + 0 = 4 \gt 1 \\
4 - 1 + 0 - 0 + 0 = 3 \gt 1 \\
4 - 0 + 0 -  0+0 = 4 \gt 1 \\
$$
And the reason we could start at $1$ on the next term is because $1$ is the largest integer $\lt \frac{4}{2} = 2$.  Those are all the cases to check for $x_0 = 4$. 
I'm wondering if in general this conjecture is true.

The terms in $S = \sum_{i = 0}^n (-1)^i x_i $ have alternating signs and are nonincreasing in magnitude, therefore is
$$ S \ge x_0 - x_1 > \frac 12 x_0 \ge \frac 12 $$
and therefore $S \ge 1$.
If $S = 1$ then $x_0 < 2S = 2$, which is only possible if $x_0 = 1$ and the remaining terms are zero.

How do you prove the first statement?

@HighAsAKiteOnMath: $S = (x_0 -x_1) + (x_2 - x_3) + (x_4 - x_5) + \cdots$, where $x_2-x_3 \ge 0$, $x_4 - x_5 \ge 0$, etc.
